# Canning for couple of days to one week of low acidic cooked food without pressure canning?

Tags: food-safety, meat, canning, pressure-canner

I would like can low acidic cooked food like vegetables or meat (chicken) to use with in couple of days to one week during summer vacations.

I dont have pressure canner so, can I do it using Hot bath canning procedure?

Answer (score 4):

NO! Using your method you have created the perfect environment to grow Clostridium botulinum, so within a couple of days you very well could have a thriving colony of botulism rich food.

From [USDA Complete Guide to Home Canning](https://nchfp.uga.edu/publications/usda/GUIDE01_HomeCan_rev0715.pdf)

> **Ensuring safe canned foods**
>
> Growth of the bacterium Clostridium botulinum in canned food may cause botulism—a deadly
>   form of food poisoning. These bacteria exist either as spores or as vegetative cells. The spores,
>   which are comparable to plant seeds, can survive harmlessly in soil and water for many years.
>   When ideal conditions exist for growth, the spores produce vegetative cells which multiply
>   rapidly and may produce a deadly toxin within 3 to 4 days of growth in an environment
>   consisting of:
>
> • a moist, low-acid food
>
> • a temperature between 40° and 120°F
>
> •  less than 2 percent oxygen.
>
> Botulinum spores are on most fresh food surfaces. Because they grow only in the absence of air,
>   they are harmless on fresh foods.
>
> Most bacteria, yeasts, and molds are difficult to remove from food surfaces. Washing fresh food
>   reduces their numbers only slightly. Peeling root crops, underground stem crops, and tomatoes
>   reduces their numbers greatly. Blanching also helps, but the vital controls are the method of
>   canning and making sure the recommended research-based process times, found in these
>   guides, are used.
>
> The processing times in these guides ensure destruction of the largest expected number of heatresistant microorganisms in home-canned foods. Properly sterilized canned food will be free of
>   spoilage if lids seal and jars are stored below 95°F. Storing jars at 50° to 70°F
>   enhances retention of quality.